# How to load a OneNote add-in published to Azure Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, add-in, onenote

I have made a OneNote add-in, as specified [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/onenote-quickstart). All local tests were successful.

This project is a prototype for the development of a proprietary OneNote add-in for a client. Hence the add-in will not be published to the Office Store.

I will not be giving a development phase add-in for my clients so following Microsoft's publishing guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish-add-in-vs-code), I have hosted the add-in as a Static Website on Azure. This process has provided me with a permanent link where the add-in will reside.

Using the [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/onenote-quickstart#:%7E:text=In%20the%20Upload%20Add%2Din%20dialog%2C%20browse%20to%20manifest.xml%20in%20your%20project%20folder%2C%20and%20then%20choose%20Upload) provided by Microsoft, add-ins will be able to be loaded from a local `manifest.xml` file. but there is no input for loading the add-in from a url.

My question is, how can the client load the add-in from the link provided?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/AkQyMfS.png, https://i.imgur.com/4isty1Z.png - Did you get the same result when accessing the static website of OneNote add-in?

Comment: no, i didn't get that. i use npm run dev-server to run the project. npm start will result in a situation like yours.

Comment: Yes! Same commands I have tried! Need to raise a ticket on GitHub for Microsoft Triage/Attention!